# How to fix 'Dummy Output' (No Sound) problem on Asus E200HA laptop?

Tags: sound

I have recently purchased Asus E200HA. This laptop had Windows 10 pre-installed on it.
As it was laggy, I created a boot able Ubuntu 17.04 USB and switched to Ubuntu. But now, I am not able to hear any audio on the device and I'm stuck.
Please provide each and every solution to this problem.
-Swastik

Comment: Use `pacmd list-card` to see if the audio card is present. If not, (re)install audio drivers. If there is an audio card, open Sound Settings and check if any slide is in the Silent position.

Comment: For info, it's `pacmd list-cards` with an 's'

Answer (score 1):

There are no audio drivers for this laptop. Apparently someone developed a new kernel and that also is not perfect. Check this out:

https://github.com/Grippentech/Asus-E200HA-Linux-Post-Install-Script

Answer (score 1):

Let's try these options in order to fix the sound problem on asus laptop.

**Install Ubuntu Audio Development Team Driver**

Open terminal and enter the following PPA:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**Reinstall Alsa and Pulse Audio**

Try to reinstall pulse audio and Alsa, open terminal and enter the following commands:

Purge Alsa and Pulse audio using the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
```

Now install again Alsa and Pulse Audio:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

Then, reload Alsa:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

I hope now you will be able to fix [asus laptop sound not working](http://www.fixotip.com/troubleshoot-sound-not-working-asus-laptop/) problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've run/tried suggestions here and elsewhere which regrettably did not work but finally was helped by script/suggestions posted on https://github.com/heikomat/linux/blob/cx2072x/cx2072x_fixes_and_manual/README.md

I (only) ran -AT OWN RISK- posted suggestion:

```
wget -qO- https://gist.github.com/heikomat/3fe272431b44b580c933bfb901a92257/raw | bash
```

after which:

1. Bluetooth sound discovered my external BT speaker
2. Sound worked fine